# Oracle PL/SQL - return table that skips over the records where error thrown

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, geospatial

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKBGEOMETRY (GEOMETRY),
       S_ROUTE,
       BLOCK_ID
  FROM GEOM_TABLE;
```

Where `GEOMETRY` is the `SDO_GEOMETRY` type. The problem is, when I run this query I get the following error which I believe is happening when I use `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKBGEOMETRY` on `GEOMETRY` records that are incorrectly specified in the database.

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oracle.spatial.util.GeometryExceptionWithContext: For GTYPE_MULTICURVE, interpretation should be 1 or 2
```

I want to write a query that simply skips over the records causing this error to be thrown (i.e. return a table that has all the rows in GEOM_TABLE except the ones throwing errors). I am new to PL/SQL and have attempted several queries involving looping and exceptions, but I have not been able to get these to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrap the funtion you're calling in another function that catches and swallows the errors. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_wkbgeometry_silent (geometry IN SDO_GEOMETRY)
    RETURN BLOB IS
BEGIN
    RETURN SDO_UTIL.to_wkbgeometry (geometry);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END to_wkbgeometry_silent;
```

Then use a sub-query to filter out the errors and avoid calling the function twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT to_wkbgeometry_silent (geometry) AS geo, s_route, block_id
        FROM   geom_table)
WHERE  geo IS NOT NULL;
```

(Though, obviously you'd be better off catching-and-ignoring the specific error you want to ignore, rather than all errors.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to skip errors, but you could avoid them by using `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE GEOMETRY WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS GEOMETRY FROM DUAL -- Fake Table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS GEOMETRY FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS GEOMETRY FROM DUAL);
```

In your exaple:

```
SELECT 
    CASE GEOMETRY WHEN 1 THEN SDO_UTIL.TO_WKBGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) WHEN 2 THEN SDO_UTIL.TO_WKBGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) ELSE NULL END,
    S_ROUTE, 
    BLOCK_ID 
FROM GEOM_TABLE;
```